# How to continuously read from a file in JavaScript without killing my CPU?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, resources

The title pretty much says it all. I'm working on an addon for an electron app, and I want to change certain settings based on what is written to a file on my local machine. I tried the following but it eats up an unhealthy chunk of my CPU.

```
var filepath = "/path/to/file";

const fs = require('fs');

var i = 1;

function readlines(file) {

const data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8');
return data;
}

while( i > 0){
    signal = readlines(filepath);

    if ( signal == "hide" ) {
        console.log("hidden");
    } else if ( signal == "show" ){
        console.log("showing")
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why don't you listen for file system change events?

Comment: @DanielA.White  didn't know that was an option. This is one of my first times writing JS, so I'm very green. I will check this out and report back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) for leading me in the right direction! The solution was to use a file system watch. The new code is as follows:

```
const filepath = "/path/to/file";

const fs = require('fs');

var i = 1;

function readlines(file) {

const data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'UTF-8');
return data;
}

fs.watch (filepath, (event, filename) => {
if (filename && event ==='change') {

    signal = readlines(filepath);
     if ( signal == "hide" ) {
         console.log("hidden");
     } else if ( signal == "show" ){
         console.log("showing");
     }
  }
 });
```